# Postfix forward incoming emails to mailin

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server, node.js

I've setup the smtp server using postfix with dovecot on mail.example.com server running on port 25.
And then I've also setup another smtp server using **mailin** (http://mailin.io) on mail.example.com server but running on port 10025.

The purpose of this mailin is simply to parse the incoming emails received from postfix and posts the parsed results as json through webhooks.

Since postfix don't have an api to parse the email content so that's why I'm using mailin.

On my **/etc/postfix/main.cf** I add this line:

```
relay_domains = localhost:10025 ## this is the mailin smtp server running on port 10025
```

Heres my maillog:

```
[root@mailserver ~]# tail -f /var/log/maillog
Dec 17 04:36:07 mailserver postfix/smtpd[6858]: connect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 17 04:36:07 mailserver postfix/smtpd[6858]: 6E2C21848: client=localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 17 04:36:07 mailserver postfix/cleanup[6868]: 6E2C21848: message-id=<20141217093607.6E2C21848@mailserver.localdomain>
Dec 17 04:36:07 mailserver postfix/qmgr[6386]: 6E2C21848: from=<arman.ortega@cebufreelancer.com>, size=506, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 17 04:36:07 mailserver postfix/smtpd[6858]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]
Dec 17 04:36:07 mailserver dovecot: lda(user1.trigger1@cebufreelancer.com): msgid=<20141217093607.6E2C21848@mailserver.localdomain>: saved mail to INBOX
Dec 17 04:36:07 mailserver postfix/pipe[6871]: 6E2C21848: to=<user1.trigger1@cebufreelancer.com>, relay=dovecot, delay=0.09, delays=0.06/0.01/0/0.02, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (delivered via dovecot service)
Dec 17 04:36:07 mailserver postfix/qmgr[6386]: 6E2C21848: removed
```

As I noticed, the email was successfully sent but the mailin doesn't work.

My question is, how does the mailin receive/parse the incoming email since the postfix 
was the only one who will received the email?

Can someone please explain how to do this properly?

**Updated [12/17/2014]: Output from postconf -n command**

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mail_owner = postfix
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
mydestination = localhost
mynetworks_style = host
myorigin = $myhostname
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_relay_domains.cf
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_alias_maps.cf
virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf
virtual_mailbox_maps = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_maps.cf
virtual_transport = dovecot
virtual_gid_maps = static:5000
virtual_uid_maps = static:5000
```

Comment: A question, are you trying to relay all mail to mailin, or just mail to certain domains?

Comment: If you want to relay all mail to mailin you'll want to change your local transport `local_transport = localhost:10025` and you'll want to define localhost in your master.cf

Comment: @NickW yeah, im trying to relay all incoming emails from postfix to mailin. Ok, i will try to edit my local_transport in my main.cf file.

Comment: Hi @NickW I added this line in master.cf
`localhost    inet  n     -       n       -       -       smtpd` then postfix reload. And I got this error
postfix/master: fatal: 0.0.0.0:localhost: Servname not supported for ai_socktype. It seems localhost is not supported?

Comment: Ah, you may want to use `127.0.0.1` instead...

Comment: @masegaloeh Hi, ive just edited my question. I added the output from postconf -n command. As you can see, I set `mynetworks_style = host` (from docs it says when Postfix should "trust" only the local machine. Since both postfix and mailin smtp servers are both on the same machine but Im not sure if this is correct.)

Comment: Okay, you state that you want **ALL** incoming emails parsed to **mailin**. Do you every email parsed by mailin AND delivered to user mailbox? Or every email just parsed by mailin?

Comment: @masegaloeh yeah, i want ALL incoming emails to be parsed by mailin. But my current setup looks like this, first it was the postfix(port 25) receives the incoming email of a user(e.g., user1@example.com, this email account was defined in **virtual_mailbox_maps** and the **virtual_transport=dovecot**), onced the email received it will store in **/var/vmail** directory. Since mailin and postfix are both smtp servers so I'm wondering if I can forward or relay the incoming emails from postfix and passed it to my mailin. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly.

Comment: @NickW I changed from localhost to 127.0.0.1 see below: <br />
`service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args` <br/>
`===============================================================` <br>
`smtp  inet  n  -  n  -  -  smtpd` <br>
`127.0.0.1  inet  n  -  n  -  - smtpd` <br>

It seems 127.0.0.1 is not a valid service name.

Comment: Hmm, now I've reread your constraits, and needs, I think you might just be able to do this with the same hooks you use for amavisd, for example `content_filter=mailin:[127.0.0.1]:10024` then define mailin in your master.cf

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm assuming that you **only** want to parsing email with *mailin* and the email won't to delivered to dovecot again.

To do that, replace the virtual_transport parameter so it becomes

```
virtual_transport = smtp:[127.0.0.1]:10025
```

That's it, instead delivering it to dovecot, postfix will pass the email to mailin via SMTP port 10025.

---

**[UPDATE]**

Based on this maillog

```
Dec 18 mailserver postfix/smtpd[13147]: connect from mailserver.cebufreelancer.com[9.40.80.111]
Dec 18 mailserver postfix/smtpd[13147]: 61C252F1F: client=mailserver.cebufreelancer.com[9.40.80.111]
Dec 18 mailserver postfix/cleanup[13157]: 61C252F1F: message-id=<20141219033146.61C252F1F@mailserver.localdomain>
Dec 18 mailserver postfix/qmgr[13139]: 61C252F1F: from=<ortegaaa@ph.ibm.com>, size=523, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec 18 mailserver postfix/smtpd[13147]: disconnect from mailserver.cebufreelancer.com[9.40.80.111]
Dec 18 mailserver postfix/smtp[13160]: 61C252F1F: to=<user1.trigger1@cebufreelancer.com>, relay=127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1]:10025, delay=0.14, delays=0.05/0.04/0/0.04, dsn=4.1.8, status=deferred (host 127.0.0.1[127.0.0.1] said: 450 4.1.8 <user1.trigger1@cebufreelancer.com>: Recipient address rejected: Domain not found (in reply to RCPT TO command))
```

Postfix successfully send the message to mailin. That error

```
Recipient address rejected: Domain not found
```

came from mailin (actually from simplesmtp, an SMTP library). See the code [in github](https://github.com/andris9/simplesmtp/blob/33a9da5abb8fe015439c0bc0f900a2d88f4b0f61/lib/server.js#L459).

Mailin would try to resolve the recipient domain when receiving email. When I try to resolve domain `cebufreelancer.com` from my VM, the result NXDOMAIN. So that's why the mailin report the error.

Comment: Hi @masegaloeh I tried the virtual_transport as you suggested but still no luck. I got this error "Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=localhost" , see my maillog at http://pastebin.com/55eBLjhN

Comment: @ArmanOrtega Try to change localhost to **[127.0.0.1]** (see my edited answer). If the mailin doesn't listen to localhost, change to your IP address, but please preserve the brackets. Actually, that's weird. I don't know why postfix refuse to resolve localhost.

Comment: Hi @masegaloeh Ive change frm localhost to 127.0.0.1, then "domain name not found" is gone. Another error came up "Recipient address rejected:Domain not found". see my maillog at http://pastebin.com/wM1ruq2F. If I use the **virtual_transport=dovecot** it works fine(I can send/receive email) since the email user1.trigger1 was saved on db by having this line: **virtual_mailbox_domains = mysql:/etc/postfix/mysql_virtual_mailbox_domains.cf** Is it the mailin cannot check/verify the email accounts on the db? instead it was the postfix who can do it? Or maybe my understanding is wrong.